# Moving a PrestaShop website

Tags: prestashop

I have moved my website built using **PrestaShop** to a new Hosting provider. And now I can access the admin backend and the site *looks* correct (all the products and pricing and images are loading).

However I am not able to edit the products in the **backend**, nor any of the carrier or other options. What could be causing this problem?

These are the steps I followed when moving my PrestaShop website:

- Created new database
- Imported backup database
- Edited `config` file with new DB name, username and password

This is my website: http://wow-maternity-sa.co.za

I am also able to register new users on the site, and they get added to the DB.  I think this shows that the site is "linking" to the newly created SQL Db

I tried that, but no luck. I have picked this up in the error log, not sure if it is useful:

[04-Sep-2016 10:23:11 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'controllers/carrier_wizard/helpers/form/form_ranges.tpl' in '/home/wowmat/public_html/admin123/themes/default/template/c‌​ontrollers/carrier_w‌​izard/helpers/form/f‌​orm.tpl' <-- thrown in /home/wowmat/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_inte‌​rnal_templatebase.ph‌​p on line 129

Comment: Have you changed the URL of the site? The shop URL is the same?

Comment: @sarcom The site URL is the same.  I transferred the domain to a new host, but the url is still the same

Comment: Try this: go in Preferences -> SEO & URL and click on save under the settings, this will regenerate the .htaccess with the rules of the new host.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck.  I have picked this up in the error log, not sure if it is useful:

[04-Sep-2016 10:23:11 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'controllers/carrier_wizard/helpers/form/form_ranges.tpl' in '/home/wowmat/public_html/admin123/themes/default/template/controllers/carrier_wizard/helpers/form/form.tpl' <-- 
  thrown in /home/wowmat/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 129

Comment: Mmm ok... Try this: delete the content of this folders `prestashop/cache/smarty/compile/` and `prestashop/cache/smarty/cache/`, don't delete index.php :)

Comment: I have deleted contents as per above (not index.php)  :)  still same errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the “carriers” issue by changing the extension of “.tp” to “.tpl”  of this file:

form_ranges.tpl in public_html/admin123/themes/default/template/controllers/carrier_wizard/helpers/form/